# Let the cubic polynomial $P(x)=x^3-ax^2+bx+c$. If the equation $P(x)=0$ has integral roots .Then why we can not say the same for $P(x)-3?$

Tags: polynomials

Consider the cubic polynomial $P(x)=x^3-ax^2+bx+c$. If the equation $P(x)=0$ has integral roots such that $P(6)=3$, then why we cannot say the same for $P(x)-3?$

Please, explain it.Thank you!

Comment: "*why we cannot say the same for* $P(x)−3$" $\;$ Try for example $\,P(x) = x^3 - 13 x^2 + 55 x - 75\,$.

Comment: @dxiv,is there any specific reason?

Comment: @Debrogli There is no reason for $P(x)-3$ to have all roots being integers, and you don't explain why you thought it would, or what made you ask this question.

Comment: You might consider a corresponding case in quadratics, where there is actually a requirement of the D bieng a perfect square as well, as the factor of a cubic has a quadratic hidden in it(if it factorises in real terms that is) them I think it becomes clearer. I think there will not neccecsarily be a proof to this, as it is case specific.